# Will sqlite column type affect performance for a long integer timestamp value?

Tags: database, sqlite

In sqlite, is it more or less performant for a large database to have a column type of INTEGER or TEXT or DATETIME or TIMESTAMP when the values are going to be epoch timestamp in ms? i.e. 1384639972645 - they all seem to work, meaning I can define them as either of those and the value gets stored the same as far as I can tell.

Is there a difference in lookup performance if there are 100,000 or 1,000,000 records with this type of value in the column between column types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite uses [dynamic typing](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) and does not care much about the declared column type; it does not matter whether you use INTEGER or TIMESTAMP or FLUFFY BUNNIES.

The only thing the column type is used for is to determine the [type affinity](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity).
If you use type TEXT, all values will be stored in the database as strings, and must be converted from/to numbers when being used. All other types have NUMERIC affinity.

If you want to document what the data type is, use a type like TIMESTAMP_MS or MILLISECONDS.

Comment: Thanks for your answer CL. Is it possible to assign conversion functionality to the column like you can with DEFAULT so that I can push my logic for storing MS vs S into the sql or sqlite built in functions vs having to do it in my app code?

Comment: What conversion funcionality? This sounds as if it should be a new question.